# How to implement multi-threading and other specific matters in vba

Tags: multithreading, vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with about 25 sheets. In some of the sheets specifically 6,7,13,17,18,19 I'm populating them with Database values. In some sheets I'm populating two table's data.
Now I need to create a button which will do the following operation.
On the button click event I need to traverse through all sheets and see if any sheet is filled.If it is filled then copy those contents to a file.I've already implemented coping one sheet contents to a file.

Question 1)
I cannot understand how to do for multiple file.

Question 2)
How to record that a particular sheet  has been populated with two table values.Since I would be needed to make one file per table.

Question 3)
Most importantly This will take a lot of time, hence I want to fasten my operations, so I want to do Multithreading. Any other way to improve speed would be great.

Comment: VBA doesn't support multitreads. To be more accurate Office does not support multithreads. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/735c8f26-2129-4b46-8c1a-aad385cab2ed for more information.
VBA is inherently slow, so careful review of your coding is important (use For..Each loops, remove variables from loops, don't use Variants, avoid '.' operators, and so on). Some gains could be had with VSTO and .NET.

Comment: How to do code optimization in vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a large time overhead whever a program reads data from Excel. This is probably the most frequent cause of complaints about speed.
To minimise this overhead you need to transfer as large a block of data as possible in each Read.
In VBA you do this by assigning a Range to a Variant:

`Dim vArr as variant

vArr=Range("A1:Z5000")`

The vArr will now contain a 2 dimensional array of 26 columns by 5000 rows.

Using .NET via Interop this technique is even more important because the time overhead is even larger than VBA.